# What is the behavior of the compiler's ctor?

Tags: c++

If I define a class's ctor and dtor like so,

```
struct Test
{
    //Test(){}
    //~Test(){}
    int a;
}

int main()
{
    Test t;
    std::cout << t.a << std::endl; 
    //^Prints garbage if ctor/dtor are defined, 0 if commented out.
}
```

Why is `a` 0 in one case and garbage in the other?

Comment: No, `a` will not be initialized in either case.

Comment: Is it all that hard to write constructor...

Comment: why is this a bad question? can downvoters pls provide some feedback?

Comment: Not downvoter, but it's really basic. Uninitialized variables are uninitialized in C++; trying to print them out gets you (at best) whatever happened to be in that memory location.

Comment: But why is it consistently 0 in one case and garbage in the other?

Comment: Because the memory location happened to have 0 in one case but not the other. It's no longer a C++ question but a "what does random memory contain with _____(compiler name)   on _____(computer type) with ____(OS version) on _____(day of week)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[class.ctor]/6

> ... The implicitly-defined default constructor performs the set of initializations of the class that would be
>   performed by a user-written default constructor for that class with no *ctor-initializer* (12.6.2) and an empty
>   *compound-statement.* ...

In other words, the constructor that the compiler generates is the same as

```
Test() {}
```

Since `a` is not explicitly initialized by the constructor, `a` is left uninitialized.

Comment: interesting, so why is `a` 0 when I don't write the ctor and garbage when I do?

Comment: '0' is a valid version of uninitialized, its probably some kind of bug hiding from the compiler vendor

Comment: If a primitive type (such as int) is not initialized, then it could end up with any arbitrary value, sometimes that value could be zero.